# Redirect to 404 if .php extension is requested

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When a user requests a page that ends with .php, I want to send them a 404 error even if the page exist. Is that possible to do with .htaccess/mod_rewrite??

http://mysite.com/whatever.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haven't tested this, but it's something like:

```
RewriteRule \.php$ - [R=404]
```

**Note**: The Added Bytes [mod_rewrite cheat sheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/) is a useful resource to have handy.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone looking for the answer to this question on IIS, you can use the annoying "feature" in IIS where it doesn't return files of types that aren't in the MimeMap Metabase.  That is, if IIS doesn't know what the file type is, it will return a 404.

This is [documented on TechNet](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/deeac9ef-cf55-4acd-86ce-b46022ff5479.mspx?mfr=true), along with [information on how to edit the Metabase](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/9bc1ebfb-6ccf-4bae-997f-f658e01e723e.mspx?mfr=true).